# How to "split" the multiple (numeric) values in XML data, in python?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, attributes

I have a list of tags like this:

```
<duet pair="2,1;3,2;4,5;" day="1;7;9" type="YES"/>
<duet pair="2,4;1,6;2,0;" day="2;5;8" type="NO"/>
```

These are wanted (type = yes) or unwanted (type = no) pairings, but imagine with various combinations and various more attributes to filter from but I will post only these for my question.  ​In this example, and lets say the first one,  I want to check  and compare (based on a schedule are already have) if any of the pairs (2,1),(3,2) or (4,5) are scheduled to be together in any of the days 1 , 7 or 9 .So, I want to seperate both the values of the pair attribute and the day attribute to proceed with my calculations.

I tried the following by getting the value with .get and splitting the it with the ";"

```
for i in root.findall("./duet/[@type='YES']"):
   meeting = i.get("pair")
   day = i.get("day")
   meeting_split = meeting.split(';')
   day_split = day.split(';')
   print("The pairs ",meeting_split)
   print("The days ", day_split)
```

The results I get are the following

```
The pairs  ['2,1', '3,2', '4,5', '']
The days ['1', '7', '9']
```

I see 2 problems with the above. 1. That these are strings and 2. That the pairs list gives me the '' at the end of the list (???) .
What I want is the pairs to be a list of tuples preferably, and the days to be a list of integers.
With the i.get , I get the entire value of the attribute, but I don't know any other way to "get" the value. And of course I can't int(day.split()), since the split result is a list.

How could I do it ? Either to actually make these data into int/tuples or to pick up the value from the attribute as one by one.

Comment: The empty string in the pairs list is inevitable because the source string ends with ';'. meeting_split[:-1] is what you need to ignore the unwanted last element. To convert the day_split to a list of integers then simply *list(map(int, day_split))* is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have the empty space at the end, because your string ends on a delimiter.  You can slice the string with `[:-1]` and split each sub string on the comma, mapping it to it.

The other is more simple, just map int to the split.

```
meeting = '2,1;3,2;4,5;'
day = "1;7;9"

meeting_split = [tuple(map(int,x.split(','))) for x in meeting.split(';')[:-1]]
day_split = list(map(int,day.split(';')))

print(meeting_split, day_split, sep='\n')
```

Output

```
[(2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 5)]
[1, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Wow. That was easier than I thought it would be and I didn't even thought of map ! Thank you !!